# A Rhyming Riley (Quite!)

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> My prefix is a spirit, some wrong, some right,
>   My infix is a place to amble a-light,
>   My suffix is often a clue on this very site,
>   My whole are things that take more than one bite.

**What am I?**

Rhyming Clue #1:

> The spirit is celebrated festivally,
> The place is vocalized electrically,
> The clue is often statistically,
> The whole is most likely fungally.

Rhyming Clue #2:

> The spirituality has a repeating sound,
> The place has grass that look like a mound,
> The clues are things that are often found,
> The whole comes in shapes, often round.

Rhyming Clue #3:

> The spirit consists of letters three,
> The full place name is too long, you see
> The clues are letters but not dee or tee,
> The whole, when warm, is quite tasty.

Non-rhyming clues:

> Several have guessed P.S. as the suffix, and it is along the right thought process, but not correct.  Look at the rhyming clues for more hints on that.

Comment: Let's see if this one lasts more than one hour.

Comment: I don't know if this is a rule for Riley's format or an error in your question, but shouldn't the infix phrase come before the suffix?

Comment: @GustavoGabriel why would that be a rule if the original had the suffix before the infix?

Comment: @Riley Couldn't find the original, some of the recent ones I saw had infix before the suffix, so I was just wondering, sorry...

Comment: please clarify the meaning of your term "a-light"...I suspect you intend to imply "with light"??

Comment: @Drt No, not "with light," more "lightly."  Poetic usage mostly. :)

Comment: Another clue, in rhyme, of course.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A bit of a long shot but:

You are

> Loaves (assuming of bread)

My prefix is a spirit, some wrong, some right

> Loa are spirits in Voudou, which is a repeated sound spirituality

My infix is a place to amble a-light

> An avenue, but shortened to "ave" because the name is too long, is definitely vocalized "electrically" in the famous song

My suffix is often a clue on this very site

> Clues that are often sought in decryption are the statistically frequent "E's". Which are, in fact, letters

My whole are things that take more than one bite.

> It seems very unlikely that someone could eat an entire loaf of bread in one bite, bread is quite delicious when warm, and the loaves would most likely be baked with yeast making them "fungally" indeed.

Comment: Not a long shot at all, congrats! What about the fungally clue?

Comment: That was the one I couldn't quite fit. I assumed it was just saying that, because bread starts molding pretty much right away, it most likely contains fungus.

Comment: What makes bread rise?

Comment: Ah, the whole yeast part. I actually did not know yeast was a fungus, that makes much more sense.

Comment: Go ahead and edit the fungally part into your answer so it's complete, when you get a chance, please.

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> Chips?

*My prefix is a spirit, some wrong, some right,*

> Chi (or qi) is a Chinese concept of life force which, in some conceptions, has different forms which *may* be wrong or right — I don't know enough about it to say for sure.

*My infix is a place to amble a-light,*

> Not 100% sure. "Hip", maybe? It's not a place in a strict sense, but in an expanded sense, it's a location in the body that's very important for walking.

*My suffix is often a clue on this very site,*

> I've seen P.S.'s in several questions on this site.

*My whole are things that take more than one bite.*

> It depends on the type of chip, but tortilla chips (among others) would be very awkward, if not impossible, to eat in one bite, speaking from personal experience.

It seems to fit the clues to some extent, although I don't know if it's the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry, no. Your suffix is along the right line.

Answer (score 2):

You are a:

> kilobyte

Reasons:

*My prefix is a spirit, some wrong, some right*

> the Ki (or qi in chinese) is an energy that flows in all living things, much like a spirit

*My infix is a place to amble a-light*

> A LOB in tennis is like a parabola (a very specific kind of curve), so this bit could be seen as the sun (a light) ambling over our heads during the day

*My suffix is often a clue on this very site*

> i'm not quite sure if this is the answer the OP wanted, but i often see bites on this site

*My whole are things that take more than one bite*

> what's more than a bite? a Kilobite!

Comment: Not bad, and I can see why you went that way, but it wasn't the word I was looking for, which should mesh much better.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer

My prefix is a spirit, some wrong, some right,

> rum is an alcoholic drink

My whole are things that take more than one bite.

> ruminate is to chew repeatedly

Comment: Nice tangent on spirit, but alas, not correct.  The clues should help.  Concentrate on the "repeating sound spirituality" part.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

> **Elanet**

*My prefix is a spirit, some wrong, some right*

> 'Elan' means 'vigorous spirit'.

*My infix is a place to amble a-light*

> That would be a 'lane'.

*My suffix is often a clue on this very site*

> A bit stumped here; I'm assuming that's 'net', though not quite sure how it's a clue on Puzzling. Maybe I should hang around here more often. ;)

*My whole are things that take more than one bite*

> Elanets are birds of prey of the genus Elanus and probably peck their prey more than once. ;)

The title and poem

> An elanet is basically a [kite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elaninae) (it derives its name from 'elanos', the ancient Greek word for kite). This fits the poem's rhyming scheme as well as the title's ('Quite').

Comment: +1 for a bird reference, but alas, nothing correct, but one fairly close.

Comment: It's the infix you're along the correct lines with.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this:

> **Kidnaps**

*My prefix is a spirit, some wrong, some right*

> I used **Ki** here to define spiritual energy as it can be used for good or bad, as in attacking someone or defending someone in martial arts.

*My infix is a place to amble a-light*

> I said **DNA** as it is the encoding material for all living things.

*My suffix is often a clue on this very site*

> **P.S.** is used often used on this site.

*My whole are things that take more than one bite*

> Kidnaps is plural so I thought that it fit with this one as you would have a lot of repercussions afterward. Kinda lost on this, to be honest. Initially, I thought it would be Chirrups. It also says *(Quiet!)* on the title which is what you tell people when you're kidnaping them.

Comment: Sorry, not there.  When I said in another comment that P.S. was on the right track for the suffix, I didn't mean to imply P.S. was correct. Also look at the clues, Ki doesn't have rhyming spirituality, does it?

Answer (score 1):

I feel like three letter spirit is most likely

> the Chinese version, Chi.

The grass-hint was strange, but

> lane fits the too-long hint and vocalizing hint.

Finally, something is often found on StackExchange, where P.S. is a good way to go but not precisely the correct answer.

Combining these clues I'm guessing

> Chilantro. Some people have in**tros** when answering a question. Chilantro is a BBQ food and I don't understand "fungally" but BBQ is most certainly warm and tasty. Chi fits spirit, lan(e) fits the second hint, so this is the best answer I got.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Could you edit your answer to include spoiler tags, so as to avoid spoiling your solution for anyone who wants to have a go at the puzzle themselves? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are a

> **BICEPS**

*My prefix is a spirit*

> Bi-spirit or [two-spirit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-spirit) is a word for bisexual people who have spiritual beliefs like native Americans.

*some wrong, some right*

> People may perceive being a bisexual as a very wrong thing, whereas people with good sense find no problem.

*My infix is a place to amble a-light*

> [Cep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cep_(Jind%C5%99ich%C5%AFv_Hradec_District)) is a very peaceful village in Czech Republic, which makes you want to take a long, relaxing walk.

*My suffix is often a clue on this very site*

> People usually give away clues using **P.S.**

*My whole are things that take more than one bite*

> Your whole is the arm. Also, only mammals have biceps. Thus, you cannot eat a whole arm (or leg) in one bite.

A wild guess, and probably wrong. But Maybe it leads to somewhere.

Comment: Sorry, no.  You're on the right path with the suffix.  I will post a clue shortly.